# WPF: Changing the view from within the view

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I want to achieve the following. I am designing a GUI with UserControls to allow the user to select and edit an action to be taken on items that the user can select elsewhere (in another part of the GUI).

Each action has a number of parameters that the user can edit (see figure). For each action I will need a different UserControl/View, since they have a different number of parameters/properties that can be edited.

As you can see in the figure, I want the user to use a drop-down menu to select and then edit an action. Therefore I need to somehow change the UserControl to that of the newly selected action from within the UserControl of the current action. How can I achieve this?!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I needed similar thing. I solved it with special Singleton class using events.

This class would have event ChangeTriggered for example and then your other `UserControl` would subscribe to it.

Now you just need one method on Singleton to trigger this change. From now on it is just matter of custom `EventArgs` to transfer the data.

I am not sure how good design this is but it worked fine. Or you can check out **Mediator design pattern**.